# How to add responsive range to a mui class?

Tags: material-ui

I have this following class in MUI4 and want to be able to apply margin in between 565-350px any idea how to put this in to one media query line ?

```js
    view: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      alignItems: 'center',
      ['@media (max-width: 565px)']: {
        marginTop: 8,
      },
      ['@media (max-width: 350px)']: {
        marginTop: 0,
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

About your question, you can try to setting like this.

```js
view: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      alignItems: 'center',
      [theme.breakpoints.up(565)]: {
      marginTop: 8,
    },
      [theme.breakpoints.up(350)]: {
      marginTop: 8,
    }
    },
```